# Why doesn't <hr />'s colour change?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following...

```
 <hr style="color:#292929;background-color:#292929;"/>
```

but the colour isn't changing to the HTML colour code I've declared. Why not?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Set `border-color`.

Comment: Haha. If it was a snake it would have bit me! So simple and I actually gave up thinking it was some super bootstrap hidden setting that I couldn't find in the miles of Bootstrap/jQuery code.

Answer (score 6):

the hr tag is a bit tricky vs other elements to style. Which things work and which ones don't is very browser dependent.

A cache of tricks (including coloration) is available here:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/style_hr_tag.htm

Answer (score 5):

just use a `p` tag with border, above unswers give no result for me...

`<p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D6D6; padding-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px"></p>`

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Changing border-colour didn't work.

Comment: This worked for me. Im not sure why, but a background-color set up in a parent element was stopping me from user <hr />. I appreciate the simple solution @den_ban

Answer (score 3):

1. Try giving it a height like 5px;
2. Give it your border styles but with 0px width.
3. Re-apply a 1px width to either top or bottom:

Result:

```
<hr style="height: 5px; border: 0px solid #D6D6D6; border-top-width: 1px;" />
```

Comment: It worked for me even without height attribute. Looks really good.

Answer (score 2):

instead of: `color:#292929;`

use: `border-color:#292929;`

Answer (score 1):

Try styling the border instead

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: No it's an answer. You style the border instead.

Answer (score 0):

try defining a height

Answer (score 0):

Sagivo, Bless you and thank you. That did the trick after a good hour+ of messing with the problem.
FYI to others I found that to get a similar look in both Outlook(the evil one) and other web clients including older IE I used this.

```
<hr size="2" width="80%" align="center" style="border-color:#878787; background:#878787">
```

Setting size to 1 made it too thick in some places, and 2 with out the background color too thin in others. This is what I ended up with. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: An HR tag is what I would call legacy HTML and like old form attributes had a forced "3D" look due to its four colored borders. In order to overcome you will need to set its borders, preferably to zero, set a height and background. I usually just use a div instead. This will work too.
`<style>
hr.hasClass{ border:0px; height:1px; background-color:#FF8600;}
</style>
<hr class="hasClass">`

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr {
    color: inherit;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

This is the bootstrap solution.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try this horizontal line(rule) better with  tag? **

```css
svg{

margin:80px auto;
}

.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1120;
/*   stroke-dashoffset: 800; */
  animation: draw1 1s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes draw1 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1120;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2240;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="line_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1200px" height="5px" xml:space="preserve">
  <path class="path2" fill="#01a09e" stroke-width="6" stroke="#01a09e" d="M0 0 l1120 0"/>
</svg>
```